¿Porqué el valor de Content del DataGridCell es nulo como parámetro en el convertidor?
estoy intentando cambiar propiedades, en este ejemplo Background, de las celdas de un DataGrid dependiendo de su contenido usando un convertidor. El problema que tengo en este ejemplo es que la propiedad Content de DataGridCell es null y no sé porqué. En este ejemplo he intentado además de la propia celda, enlazar el objeto Content, para usarlas en el convertidor pero también es nulo. Es decir, values[0] en el convertidor es null y también DataGriCell.Content y no sé porqué.
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Vista:CellConverter x:Key="ConvertidorCelda"/>
</UserControl.Resources>


<DataGrid x:Name="dgPrincipal"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          AllowDrop="True"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ListaModelos}">

    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConvertidorCelda}">
                            <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>

</DataGrid>

ejemplo del convertidor.
namespace UIHojaCambiosPrincipal.Views
{
     public class CellConverter : IMultiValueConverter
     {
          public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
          {
             if (values[1] is DataGridCell celda && values[0] is TextBlock txtBlock)
             {
               try
               {
                   // Cambiar el color según el contenido 
                  string contenidoCelda = txtBlock.Text;
                  if(contenidoCelda == string.Empty)
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue);
               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black); 
               }
           }
           return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkRed); 
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }}

¿Quizás pueda estar relacionado en la lista de enlace del DataGrid ListaModelos?
    public class PrincipalViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ModelosViewModel _modelosViewModel;

    private ObservableCollection<List<string>> _ListaColeccionModelos = new ObservableCollection<List<string>>();
    public ObservableCollection<List<string>> ListaModelos
    {
        get => _ListaColeccionModelos;
        set
        {
            if (_ListaColeccionModelos != value)
            {
                _ListaColeccionModelos = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_ListaColeccionModelos));
            }
        }
    }


    public PrincipalViewModel()
    {
        _modelosViewModel = new ModelosViewModel();
        _ListaColeccionModelos = _modelosViewModel.ObtenerListaModelos();
    }

}

Seguro que se me escapa algo pero no consigo verlo. ¿alguna idea?.
